# Marketcap increase/decrease

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Is it possible in pinescript to have a simple strategy that buys/sells when the marketcap of a cryptocurrency increases/decreases by a certain amount e.g. by 3% or $10 million. I don't have any code currently as I'm unsure how to start. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This will work only for several (popular) cryptocurrencies:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)
change = input(3, title = "MktCap 1D percent change")/100.0
rr(s, bb)=>(s - s[bb])/s
signal(s, bb)=>
    rr = rr(s, bb)
    long = rr >= change
    short = rr <= -change
    [long, short]

[long, short] = request.security("CRYPTOCAP:"+syminfo.basecurrency, "D", signal(close,1))
if (long)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
if (short)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Comment: Thank you Andrey! Also, where in that code does it specify the percentage increase by and can it be an increase/decrease by an absolute value such as $5 million, for example?

Comment: This is "how to start" example. You can make other needed changes yourself ;-)

Comment: Ok :), but would you be able to explain the 'signal' function please?

Comment: The signal function returns golong or goshort signals by your condition "when the marketcap of a cryptocurrency increases/decreases by a certain amount e.g. by 3%". If MktCap of crypto daily change is more than `change` %% - golong, if first one is less than `-change` %% - goshort